GEE Featurecollection sorting problem
I have problem with the order of featurecollection. I found the order of featurecollection changed when uploading csv or exporting featurecollection to Assets, even if an ee.FeatureCollection.Sort operation is adopted.
As shown in the below figure, I hope the featurecollection is sorting by the Index column from 0 to maximum, but the uploading/export results are not ideal.

My code is below:
var LUT = ee.FeatureCollection('users/SiJia/GEE_LUT/LUT/1_56w');

var LUT_sorted = LUT.sort('Index');

LUT_sorted=LUT_sorted.map(function(f){
  var newGeometry =ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]);
  f=f.setGeometry(newGeometry);
  return f;
});

Export.table.toAsset({collection:LUT_sorted, 
                      description:'LUT_sorted', 
                      assetId:"GEE_LUT/1_56w_sorted"});

Do you have any suggestions?
